# Find most active or most recent userid by machineid

Tags: sql, count, grouping

I have a table with MachineID, UserID and Date columns.  Each day I insert/append into this table a record of which user logs onto which machine, so I end up with a daily historical log of users logged into machines.  I need to be able to extract from this the most active user for a machine (the UserID with the most rows against a MachineID), or in the case that two users are tied for "first place", the most recent of those two users.

I'm running SQL 2012 Express.  Basically I've got to the point where I have the MachineID and UserID and the number of dates/rows for each combination of these, but I can't figure out how to get any further.

Using the sample data set of:

```
[MachineID] [UserID] [Date]
1   1   20190619
1   1   20190620
1   2   20190621
2   3   20190618
2   3   20190619
2   4   20190620
2   4   20190621
```

I've run the SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT MachineID
    , UserID
    , COUNT(DTAdded) as [Logon Count]
FROM MUHistory
GROUP BY MachineID, UserID
```

and the result is:

```
[MachineID] [UserID]    [Logon Count]
1   1   2
1   2   1
2   3   2
2   4   2
```

However my desired result is:

```
[MachineID] [UserID]
1   1
2   4
```

Where on MachineID '1' the User '1' has logged on more than any other user, and on MachineID '2' UserID '3' and '4' have both logged on the same number of times, but of these UserID '4' has the most recent logon.

Thanks in advance, I've had a search around but I can only find posts on getting one or the other result (most active or most recent) but not the two combined.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm running MS SQL Server 2012 Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I first find the counts of login to a machine by each user using the count(*) , then I use this count to rank the rows order by count and date inorder to pick the most recent one incase there is a tie.

```
with a as 
  (     
Select 1 MachineID,  1 UserID,  20190619 Date union all
Select 1 ,  1  , 20190620 union all
Select 1 ,  2  , 20190621 union all
Select 2 ,  3  , 20190618 union all
Select 2 ,  3  , 20190619 union all
Select 2 ,  4  , 20190620 union all
Select 2 ,  4  , 20190621
)
, b as 
(
Select MachineID,UserID, date,
count(*) over (partition by MachineID,UserID order by date asc) cnt
from a
)
,c as 
(
select *
,row_number() Over(partition by MachineID order by cnt desc,date desc) fn
from b
) 
Select MachineID,UserID,date
from c
where fn=1;
```

o/p:

```
MachineID   UserID  date
 1          1      20190620
 2         4       20190621
```

Comment: Mate, that is amazing, thankyou very much!  I've seen references to this 'partition by' stuff before but I honestly have no idea how it works - turns out this will be a bit of research for me  :)

Comment: yeah very useful , if you master it than you can do lots.